Ruler and compass construction of an inscribed quadrilateral
Suppose that I have a (convex) quadrilateral $ABCD$. In the interior of it I have 4 distinct points $P,Q,R,S$ in general position (i.e. are vertex of a quadrilateral). The question how to construct a (convex) quadrilateral inscribed in $ABCD$ (so each corner of the quadrilateral must lie on a unique edge of $ABCD$) such that each edge of it will contain exactly one point of $P,Q,R,S$ is easy to answer using analytic geometry. It will have at most two solutions so it can be obtained from the roots of a quadratic equation. This is a sign that the construction of this inscribed quadrilateral can be done via ruler and compass (or by some intersection of conic sections and lines). Could anyone come up with a geometric solution using ruler and compass if such a solution exist?

Please include the analytic geometry solution you know. It could give hints about a synthetic solution without having to start from scratch and duplicate your effort.

what happens if PQRS do not form a  convex quadrilateral, as one of them is in the convex hull of the other three?

Maybe it is not a convex one in that order, but there will always be permutation of it that is a convex one.

You cannot draw a line through the "mid-point" so that three other points lie in the same half-plane.

What you ask is impossible. Think of the case when none of the points $PQRS$ lies inside triangle $ABC$: that side of the inscribed quadrilateral having its vertices on $AB$ and $BC$ cannot pass through any point among $PQRS$. There must be some additional condition, I suppose.

I think your request should be reformulated as "construct the inscribed quadrilateral given  four points on it, one on each side", or something like that.

@Intelligenti: Yes, I think you are right. But I wanted a ruler-compass construction if a solution exist. I modified it a bit to stress this. Feel free to modify the question if you still think it is unclear.


Comment:
Consider the picture. To construct wanted quadrilateral we first find the project of points P, Q, R and S on adjacent sides of the quadrilateral:
K and L are the projections of P and S on side AD.
J and $B_1$ are the projections of P and Q on the side AB.
U and Z are the projections of Q and R on the side BC.
$A_1$and W are the projections of R and S on the side CD.
The vertexes of required quadrilateral must be between the projections of points on the sides.As can be seen only quadrilateral in blue satisfies the condition.
